# Static HashMap Initialization

Tags: java, spring, hashmap

I have this class, I want to know:
1° Is this the best way to define a static HashMasp
2° Is this the best way to do it in a Spring based app?(does Spring offer a better way to do this?)

Thanks in advance!

```
    public class MyHashMap {
        private static final Map<Integer, String> myMap;
        static {
            Map<CustomEnum, String> aMap = new HashMap<CustomEnum, String>();
            aMap.put(CustomEnum.UN, "one");
            aMap.put(CustomEnum.DEUX, "two");
            myMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(aMap);
        }

        public static String getValue(CustomEnum id){
            return myMap.get(id);
        }
    }


    System.out.println(MyHashMap.getValue(CustomEnum.UN));
```

Comment: Might be interesting to know that as of java 9 you'll be able to create map on the go in a similar way to Arrays.asList which would allow you to avoid the static block. Trying to find where I've read that already...

Comment: There you go... [`Map.ofEntries`](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries-java.util.Map.Entry...-) and [`Map.of(...)`](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard You should create an answer with this.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few approaches to doing this. For example if your map is immutable you could consider using the [Google Guava libraries](https://github.com/google/guava)
It has an ImmutableMap class which could be used to construct your map as:-

```
static final ImmutableMap<String, Integer> WORD_TO_INT =
       new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Integer>()
           .put("one", 1)
           .put("two", 2)
           .put("three", 3)
           .build();
```

If you are already using the [Spring Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html) and wiring your beans using XML, then you could fill the map in directly via the XML as :-

```
    ...    
<!-- creates a java.util.Map instance with the supplied key-value pairs -->
<util:map id="emails">
    <entry key="pechorin" value="pechorin@hero.org"/>
    <entry key="raskolnikov" value="raskolnikov@slums.org"/>
    <entry key="stavrogin" value="stavrogin@gov.org"/>
    <entry key="porfiry" value="porfiry@gov.org"/>
</util:map>
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Either you can use Guava library. But if you dont want to use 3rd party library, then there are two ways to do it:

1. Static initializer

   ```
   private static final Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
   static {
        myMap.put(key1, value1);
        myMap.put(key2, value2);
   }

   public static Map getMap() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(myMap);
   }
   ```
2. Instance initialiser (anonymous subclass).

   ```
   private static final Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>()
   {
      {
        put(key1, value1);
        put(key2, value2);
      }
   };

   public static Map getMap() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(myMap);
   }

   private static void addPair(String key, String val){
        // Add key val to map
   }
   ```

Suppose later on you want to add some constant to map, then you can do that as well.

**Collections.unmodifiableMap**: It helps to have a unmodifiable view of map, which can not be modified. As it gives unsupported-Exception, if any modification is made to map.